# Transparent GridView in ASP .Net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, transparency

I wonder if is there any way to make a `GridView` *transparent*.
I know that the borders can be made transparent and i know how to do it,

[image: GridView Screenshot]

but the area **1** and **2** in the image, *backgrounds of the cells* and *titles* are my concern.
i prefer to keep my original background image so i prefer transparency. But if it's a no go
i can accept to add a background image too i guess.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the built in styles of a GridView.  For example, your gridview might look something like:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" 
    BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
</asp:GridView>
```

If that is the case, just remove all of your styles like so:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1">
</asp:GridView>
```

Alternatively, you can override the inline styles of the Gridview using CSS and the !important property like so (you'll need to update the CSS accordingly):

```
<style type="text/css">
    table {background:transparent !important;}
    table tr {background:transparent !important;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a small image that is transparent.
Then use css to add it to the table:

```
    table
    {
        background-image: Transparent5by5.gif;
    }
```